# Sending extras with an intent returned by getLaunchIntentForPackage() to the main activity of another app

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to launch an app with extras, from a notification. I get the launch intent for it using:

```
Intent launchIntentForApp = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
```

**Note:** The context is of the same app itself. I'm trying to build a library which can be used in my other apps.

I add a few extras to it by:

```
launchIntentForApp.putExtra("test", true);
```

Then I create a pending intent for it, and add it to the notification drawer:

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, launchIntentForApp, 0);
Notification n = new Notification.Builder(context)
                    .setContentTitle(notifTitle)
                    .setContentText(notifMessage)
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(notifMessage))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.color.transparent)
                    .build();
            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(0, n);
```

However, when the activity is launched of that app, in the onCreate() of that activity, the following always returns null:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

How do I go about sending extra information to that app's main activity?

Answer (score -1):

Try:
`Bool s=getIntent().getStringExtra("test");`

Comment: try "obj =getIntent().getSerializableExtra("test");"